# How do I convert number of minutes to interval in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a `duration` column of type `time(7)` in my `appointments` table.

I know how to get the number of minutes in an appointment using

```
select durationMinutes = DateDiff(n, a.StartOn, a.EndOn) 
from appointments a
```

but my `duration` column is `time(7)`.

How do I convert the `int` to the `duration`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @Time as Time(7) = '01:02:03';
select @Time as 'Time(7)', DateDiff( minute, 0, @Time ) as 'Minutes';

declare @Minutes as Int = 90;
select @Minutes as 'Minutes', Cast( DateAdd( minute, @Minutes, 0 ) as Time(7) ) as 'Time(7)';
```

Comment: What is the significance of declaring @Time in this answer?

Comment: @kirsteng - Just showing examples of conversion in both directions: `TIME(7)` to `INT` and `INT` to `TIME(7)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the DATEADD function and add the minutes to a 00:00:00 time.

```
DATEADD(MINUTE, @durationMinutes, '00:00:00')
```

Comment: This seems to work. However confusingly MSDN mentions that the return type would be a DateTime if there is a string literal in the 3rd argument.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: I think you can easily convert datetime to time